# ms access gives run time error 2471 during Dlookup

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that allows the user to add records to a table. I am trying to add a button that will allow them to copy the currently displayed record to a new record.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Command1947_Click()
    Dim currentID As Long
 
    If IsNull(Panel_ID) Then
        MsgBox prompt:="Please select the record to copy first.", buttons:=vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    currentID = Panel_ID
    DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNewRec
    
    
    MsgBox prompt:=DLookup("Job_Number", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID), buttons:=vbExclamation
    
    Job_Number = DLookup("Job_Number", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Date_of_MFG = DLookup("Date_of_MFG", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    'Build_Hours = DLookup("Build_Hours", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Quality_Initials = DLookup("Quality_Initials", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Builders = DLookup("Builders", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    'Shop_Location = DLookup("Shop_Location", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Customer_Name = DLookup("Customer_Name", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Customer_Part = DLookup("Customer_Part", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    'Ship_First_Pass = DLookup("Ship_First_Pass", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    LOM = DLookup("LOM", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    'Prints_Red_Lined = DLookup("Prints_Red_Lined", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Quality_Touch_Points = DLookup("Quality_Touch_Points", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    Spot_Checker_Initials = DLookup("Spot_Checker_Initials", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    'Drawings_Highlighted = DLookup("Drawings_Highlighted", "Table1", "Panel_ID=" & currentID)
    
End Sub
```

Panel Id is my primary key and is an autogenerated sequential number.
Table1 is the name of the table that contains the data.

When I run the code Build Hours, Shop Location, Ship First Pass, Prints Red Lined, and Drawings Highlighted all give me:

Run-time error '2471': The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Build_Hours'

[image: Error Image]

Build Hours is a decimal number and the other 4 that generate the error are all short text. It seems like the code can't find these fields within the table.

In addition, when set the 5 fields that generate the error as notes and run the rest of the code, all of the other fields only seem to return null values to the new record.

Right now it seems like the MsgBox and moving to a new record after getting the Panel ID from the old record are the only parts that are working.

I learned how to use Access a long time ago but it seems to have changed a lot since and I am basically relearning it as I use it and with the help of google searches so please be patient with me.

Comment: What is the text message that goes with that error #? We shouldn't have to Google to get the information needed in order to help you. When you mention an error, the very next thing you should add is the **complete, exact error message** that you're getting. Please [edit] to add that information. You're asking us for our free help to solve your problem - it's in your best interest to make it as easy for us as possible by giving us the details.

Comment: Instead of multiple DLookup calls to the same table, could open a recordset which would be a single call. But why do either when data is already displayed on form? Could set variables to selected record data, move to new record row, set values of controls with variables. Your table is actually named "Table1"? Should use more descriptive name.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to open and call a recordset or pull data directly from the form. I am not familiar with Visual Basic at all and it has been almost 15 years since I last used Access, so I'm trying to learn how to do all this as I go. I only went with the Dlookup because its what someone else used on another forum post on another site to do something similar. I have no problems redoing my code if there is a better way. I just don't know what those ways are.

Comment: All of my field names contain spaces instead of underscores but when I used a space I received a different error saying that I was missing a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume Panel_ID is a number type. Also assume controls have same names as fields they are bound to.

If field names have space instead of underscore, enclose in `[ ]`.  Use form prefix to reference form's fields and controls. `Me` can be used as alias for form name in code behind that form.

```
With Me
    currentID = .[Panel ID]
    DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNewRec
    .[Job Number] = DLookup("[Job Number]", "Table1", "[Panel ID]=" & currentID)
    ...
End With
```

Instead of multiple calls with DLookup, do one call to open a recordset object and pull data.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
With Me
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [Panel ID] =" & .[Panel ID])
    DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNewRec
    .[Job Number] = rs![Job Number]
    ...
End With
```

Alternatively, since data has already been pulled by bound form:

```
Dim JN, DOM, ...
With Me
    JN = .[Job Number]
    DOM = .[Date of Mfg]
    ...
    DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNewRec
    .[Job Number] = JN
    .[Date of Mfg] = DOM
    ...
End With
```

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention nor reserved words as names.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Using variables from the bound form option worked perfectly. I appreciate the help.